# How can i sort with excel formula 5 rows?

Tags: excel, formula

i wont to sort more than one row in excel see image how the excel is  :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oS88H.jpg

The result that i want is :

```
PD 8123
PS 7654
PD 4061
PS 3827
LS 3122
LI 2112
PD 2030
PS 1913
```

Please any help , i tried with sort and with rank formula but no luck .

Answer (score 2):

Enter the following formula in `Cell G2` :

```
=LARGE($A$2:$D$7,ROW()-1)
```

Drag/copy down as required.

Enter the following formula in `Cell F2` :

```
=INDEX($A$1:$D$1,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($A$2:$D$7=G2)*(COLUMN($A$2:$D$7))))-COLUMN($A$1)+1)
```

Drag/copy down as required.

See image for reference.

[image]